# Xamarin Forms references the wrong version of mscorlib (FSharp.Core)

Tags: android, f#, xamarin.forms

Create a new blank solution in Visual Studio 2015.

Add a new Blank App (Android) under the F# menu.

Add the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package, Version 2.3.3.175.

The following warning message appears as a popover in `MainActivity.fs`:

> The referenced or default base CLI library 'mscorlib' is
>   binary-incompatible with the referenced F# core library 'C:...\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.175\lib\MonoAndroid10\FormsViewGroup.dll'. Consider recompiling
>   the library or making an explicit reference to a version of this
>   library that matches the CLI version you are using.

Later, when I try to instantiate a viewmodel (using ReactiveUI as my MVVM provider), I get this runtime error:

[image]

This usually happens because the wrong version of `FSharp.Core` is being referenced. It appears that this is a bug.

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Is it this [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42986)?